# Multiple root tags error

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I'm new to Android development and programming in general. I tried to write some layout code but I'm getting

```
Multiple root tags error
```

Anyone who can help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is my first android app!" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello!" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is my first android app!" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I was able to fix it this way, but it doesn't work if in the first TextView text I put "@string/Hello" can someone tell me why?

Comment: Looks good to me. Maybe show the code where you use the layout?

Comment: RubyDerBoss where is it? i'm sorry i'm new to this stuff

Comment: First element is closed... But it shouldn't.

Comment: Now i'm getting even the "Tag is not closed" error. I can't upload a screenshot because i need more reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is my first android app!" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button!" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand the fix. Would you mind explaining for myself and future users?

Comment: @TimothyBomer The question has been edited, initially the linear layout tag was closed there only making multiple root tags.